# Websites to share transcriptions?

Tags: resource-request

I often come across interesting video content on Youtube  in my target language (Russian) that don't have transcriptions or at very least only have sketchy YouTube closed caption auto transcriptions. I wondered if there is any website or community in which people can request content to be transcribed in their target language in exchange for transcribing content in their native language? There is a really cool site called 3ears.com (I am not affiliated) for Russian but I prefer to learn from content which I enjoy and can personally choose. The site is a bit limited in the content offering.

Comment: Transcriptions of what specifically? There are many things that can have transcripts.

Comment: Welcome to languagelearning.SE! You might want to add a parenthetical note about whether you are affiliated to the 3ears website or not.

Comment: maybe give trint.com a try?